# ZSH shell and CLion/PyCharm integration, movement around terminal

Tags: shell, pycharm, zsh, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to use zsh in the CLion terminal window (changed my shell to `/bin/zsh`)

But when I try to move around using <kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>... I get the literal characters `D`, `C` and <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd> opens the "Recent files" UI

Is there any way around this? I'd like to use the movement keystrokes as I can with bash.

Answer (score 0):

Tempoz,

Check out the [offical Zsh Line Editor doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) and the [Z-Shell Line Editor guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html) for tons of detail.

To start, you can see your current mappings by typing `bindkey` at your prompt. There are two start modes: emacs [default], and vi. If you want to use vi mode, add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey -v
```

and source it (or restart your shell, or restart your IDE). Check out how the `bindkey` output has changed.

If you decide you want to change or augment your key mappings, use `bind` in your `~/.zshrc` to reassign, or add to your key map.

```
# Example key binding change
# bindkey key-sequence editor-command
bindkey '^Z' vi-kill-line
```

You will also probably want to fix your $PATH - all the JetBrains products do it incorrectly. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006003/1089228